# Distribute list behavior on outgoing routing updates

Tags: eigrp

i have this topology
[image]

I'm studying route maps and pbr and distribution list , I advertise bunch of network address from R4 and R5 and R7
,i managed to leverage route maps and distribute list to remove certain entries from R6 routing table by applying distribution list inbound in eigrp , as i understand this will only effect incoming routes so R7 should only get the filtered version of R6 RIB , but here is the weird thing when applying distribution list on R6 the R7 addresses don't get advertised not to R6 and of course to no other routers, so my question is how should I keep the same behavior of distribute list and in same time advertise R7 addresses? What should I change? Thanks

```
R6#sh ip int brie | ex unassigned
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         172.16.56.6     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet1/0         172.16.46.6     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Ethernet2/0                172.16.36.6     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Ethernet2/1                172.16.26.6     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Ethernet2/2                10.10.10.6      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Loopback0                  6.6.6.6         YES NVRAM  up                    up      
R6#sh run 
interface Ethernet2/2
 ip address 10.10.10.6 255.255.255.0
 ip policy route-map RM1
router eigrp 123
 distribute-list route-map RM2 in 
 network 6.6.6.0 0.0.0.255
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 172.16.26.0 0.0.0.255
 network 172.16.36.0 0.0.0.255
 network 172.16.46.0 0.0.0.255
 network 172.16.56.0 0.0.0.255 
ip prefix-list PL1 seq 10 permit 55.55.0.0/16 ge 27 le 29       
ip prefix-list PL2 seq 5 permit 44.44.0.0/16 ge 24 le 26
ip prefix-list PL2 seq 10 permit 44.44.0.0/16 ge 30 le 30     
ip prefix-list PL3 seq 10 permit 10.7.0.0/16 ge 24
ip prefix-list PL3 seq 20 permit 10.2.0.0/16 ge 24
access-list 101 permit icmp host 10.10.10.7 any
access-list 102 permit ip any any            
route-map RM2 permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list PL1         
route-map RM2 permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list PL2         
route-map RM1 permit 10
 match ip address 101
 set ip next-hop 172.16.56.5         
route-map RM1 permit 20
 match ip address 102
 set ip next-hop 172.16.36.3
 R6#sh ip route | ex L
      6.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.10.10.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet2/2
      44.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 3 masks
D        44.44.2.0/24 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.46.4, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet1/0
D        44.44.3.0/26 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.46.4, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet1/0
D        44.44.3.80/30 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.46.4, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet1/0
D        44.44.4.0/26 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.46.4, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet1/0
      55.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 3 masks
D        55.55.1.0/28 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.56.5, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet0/0
D        55.55.3.0/29 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.56.5, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet0/0
D        55.55.3.32/27 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.56.5, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet0/0
D        55.55.4.0/29 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.56.5, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet0/0
D        55.55.4.32/27 
           [90/130816] via 172.16.56.5, 00:38:53, GigabitEthernet0/0
      172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 2 masks
C        172.16.26.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet2/1
C        172.16.36.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet2/0
C        172.16.46.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet1/0
C        172.16.56.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
R1#sh ip route
--output ommited--
      10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D        10.10.10.0 [90/282112] via 192.168.15.5, 06:40:35, GigabitEthernet0/0
                    [90/282112] via 192.168.14.4, 06:40:35, GigabitEthernet1/0
R1#sh ip route          
      10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D        10.10.10.0 [90/282112] via 192.168.15.5, 00:07:09, GigabitEthernet0/0
                    [90/282112] via 192.168.14.4, 00:07:09, GigabitEthernet1/0
                    [90/307456] via 192.168.13.3, 00:07:09, Ethernet2/1
                    [90/307456] via 192.168.12.2, 00:07:09, Ethernet2/0
R1#trac 10.10.10.7
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.10.10.7
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
  1 192.168.12.2 8 msec 20 msec 4 msec
  2  *  *  * 
  3  *  *  * 
  4  *  * 
  
R2(config-if)#do trac 10.10.10.7
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.10.10.7
  1 172.16.26.6 24 msec 16 msec 8 msec
  2 10.10.10.7 12 msec 24 msec 28 msec
R2(config-if)#do sh run 
interface Loopback11
 ip address 2.2.2.222 255.255.255.255
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.12.2 255.255.255.0        
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 ip address 172.16.26.2 255.255.255.0  
router eigrp 123
 network 2.2.2.222 0.0.0.0
 network 172.16.26.0 0.0.0.255
 network 192.168.12.0
```

i put the impotent info , if you need more i will edit the post

Comment: Are you trying to work with distribute lists in EIGRP or policy based routing (PBR) ?  It seems like the PBR map on R6 is redirecting all ICMP inbound from R7 to R2 and all remaining traffic inbound from R7 to R3.   Your route-map is also preventing R6 from advertising any of the inter-router links (...which notably includes the addresses you're trying to trace from), so if it were to work it would have to be sourced between loopback addresses.  Maybe it would make more sense if you started over and described what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: you are right i been studying route map application i deployed them to do some pbr and distribution list, i did not think of the consequences of directing every thing other than icmp in one direction , but i dont think it is the pbr route map issue because when i remove the distribution list and keep the pbr untouched every  thing return to normal, the problems occur when i apply the distribution list inbound in eigrp configuration